# problem with nested while loops (bash)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do nested while loops in bash

**My code:**

```
while true 
do
echo "enter the command"
    while read line
    do    
        commArray=("${commArray[@]}" $line)    
    done    
    echo "ok"
done
```

My problem is that when I write the command in the stdin the while never gets to the "ok" part.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `read` fail, you neet to close its input. For input from the terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> to send EOF.